# Frequency response of low pass filter

Tags: low-pass, passive-filter, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency

I have an ideal low pass filter having cutoff frequency 1kHz. If I provide an input having single frequency component at 1kHz, will there be any output or zero?

Comment: How do you propose to have a single component at 1kHz? You would need a sine wave that has existed forever.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Why does it have to have existed forever?

Comment: @Carl if not there will be frequency components other than 1kHz.

Answer (score 2):

Explain: "I have an `ideal` low pass filter"... Soon this will become a question on limits and discontinuities.

Assuming that you have an ideal brick-wall filter, then if you approach the limit from the left, the answer would be yes, there will be a non-attenuated output. If you approach from the right, there will be no output.

In real life there are no discontinuities.

Comment: I have a question related to sampling and reconstruction of signal. The only sample is at 500kHz which is passed through an ideal low pass filter having cutoff frequency 500kHz before reconstruction. The output here shows zero.

Comment: Post a new question and include the details. Saying "output here shows zero" does not help anyone. Regarding your query, I would ask you the same question: Did you approach the limit from the left or the right?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a "cut-off" of a single-pole filter means it is 3db attenuation of the input signal.  More poles, more attenuation but not zero.

Comment: Yes that 3db attenuation happens when I am considering a practical LPF, but what about an ideal low pass filter? Will I get any output at cutoff frequency or only at frequencies less than cutoff?

Comment: An "ideal" filter is not a "brick wall" to frequencies on the other side of the cutoff.   An "ideal filter" behaves like a filter is supposed to act with no exceptions or anomalies/unplanned resonances.

Comment: @GTElectronics OP means the mathematical concept, the ideal case, whose inverse Fourier transform gives a sinc() (from \$-\infty\$ to \$\infty\$).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeterminate since it is not defined what the response of an 'ideal filter' is at precisely the cutoff frequency.

However and 'ideal filter' like that also has infinite delay, so there will be no output in a finite time anyway.

Comment: The 2nd part is only true if it's a causal filter. Since you're dealing with an ideal one, the delay can be zero.